# Convolution of x(t) and x(-t)

Tags: integration, exponential-function, convolution, signal-processing, step-function

Consider the signal $x(t)=e^{-t}u(t)$ 
 where $u(t)=\mathbb{1}(t\geq0)$, i.e. the Heaviside function.

Find the signal $y(t)=x(t)*x(-t)$

My attempt:

$y(t)=x(t)*x(-t)$

$=e^{-t}u(t)*e^{t}u(-t)$

$=e^{-t}u(t)*e^{t}u(-t)$

$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[e^{-\tau}u(\tau)][e^{t-\tau}u(-t+\tau)]d\tau $

$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{t}e^{-2\tau}u(\tau)u(-t+\tau)d\tau $

$= e^{t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2\tau}u(\tau)u(-t+\tau)d\tau $

$= e^{t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{-2\tau}d\tau $ *(I think)*

$=e^{t}[(-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2\tau}]_0^t$

$=-\frac{1}{2}e^{t}[e^{-2t}-1]$

$=\frac{1}{2}[e^{t}-e^{-t}]$

The solution and Wolfram Alpha give $y(t)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-|t|}$. Did I evaulate the step functions wrong? Guidance is appreciated.

Comment: what if $t$ is a negative value? For that case, the integration region wouldn't be like from $0$ to $t$

Comment: I don't think there is a close for expression unless $u$ has some special form.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz In this context $u$ means the unit step function, also known as the Heaviside function.

Comment: Do you mean $u(t)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)}(t)$? if so, the problem is trivial.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need $u(\tau)$ and $u(-t+\tau)$ to both be $1$, so $\tau > 0$ and $\tau > t$. So, if $t > 0$, then this becomes $\tau > t$, and your integral (in the line where you say "I think") should actually have limits $t$ to $\infty$. This gives $y(t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-t}$ for $t > 0$.

On the other hand, if $t < 0$, this becomes $\tau > 0$, so your integral should have limits $0$ to $\infty$. This gives $y(t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{t}$ for $t < 0$. Putting this together with the solution in the $t > 0$ case, you can see that $y(t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-\left\lvert t\right\rvert}$ covers both cases in a single expression.

Answer (score 0):

If $u(t)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)}(t)$, then 
$$ u(\tau) u(-t+\tau)=\mathbb{1}_{(t,\infty)}(\tau), \qquad t>0$$
$$ u(\tau)u(-t+\tau)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)}(\tau), \qquad t\leq0$$ 
Thus
\begin{aligned}
 e^t\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-2\tau}u(\tau)u(-t+\tau)\,d\tau&= e^t\int^\infty_{t}e^{-2\tau}\,d\tau = \frac{1}{2}e^{-t}
\end{aligned}
for $t>0$, and
\begin{aligned}
 e^t\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-2\tau}u(\tau)u(-t+\tau)\,d\tau&= e^t\int^\infty_0e^{-2\tau}\,d\tau = \frac{1}{2}e^t
\end{aligned}
for $t\leq0$. In other words, the solution is $G(t):=\frac{1}{2}e^{-|t|}$.